# How is biometric for vigenette transfer visit visa done

Tags: visas, uk

When filling the application of vigenette transfer visit visa because of lost passport and visa. After submitting the form and signing declaration next step is biometric transfer which gives only Uk address and doesn’t show the address of the country form is being filled in. How to get the address of the city ( karachi )where we will submit the form.